# how do i get the current year and compare it with the file.text name

Tags: codeigniter

example: i have this file name **change log 2013.txt** but when its 2014, I want it to create new file name **change log 2014.txt**

Anyone can help? this is my controller:

```
<?php
class changelog extends Controller {

    function changelog()
    {
        parent::Controller();
                $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    function index()
    {
                  $this->change_log_add();
    }

        function change_log_view()
        {
            $data['message'] = read_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt');
            $this->load->view('change_log_view', $data);
        }

        function change_log_add()
        {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Please Insert the task changed');

                $data['action'] = 'changelog/change_log_save_add/';

                $this->load->view('change_log_form', $data);


        }

        function change_log_save_add()
        {
              if($this->input->post('message') != NULL)
            {
                date_default_timezone_set ("Asia/Singapore");

                $data = date("Y-m-d, H:i:s");
                $body = $this->input->post('message');
                $text = $data.' - '.$body."\r\n";

                    if ( ! write_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt', $text, 'a+'))
                        {
                            echo 'Unable to write the file';
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'File Written');
                            redirect('changelog/change_log_read/');
                        }


            }
        }
        function change_log_read()
        {
            if(read_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt') == NULL)
            {
                echo 'File is Empty!';
            }
            else
            {

                $string = read_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt');
                echo $string;
                redirect('changelog/change_log_view/');
            }
        }

        function change_log_update()
        {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Please Insert the task changed');

                $data['message'] = read_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt');
                $data['action'] = 'changelog/change_log_save_update/';

                $this->load->view('change_log_form', $data);
        }

        function change_log_save_update()
        {
            if($this->input->post('message') != NULL)
            {

                $message = $this->input->post('message');

                if ( ! write_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt', $message, 'r+'))
                    {
                        echo 'Unable to write the file';
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'File Written');
                        redirect('changelog/change_log_read/');
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *sidenote:* recommend not to use filename containing spaces & special characters. Use only alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each appearance of `change log 2013.txt`, replace it with :

```
'change log ' . date('Y') . '.txt'
```

For example, instead of :

```
write_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log 2013.txt', $message, 'r+')
```

change it to:

```
write_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\change log ' . date('Y') . '.txt', $message, 'r+')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the static 2013 to use php date instead, this should be change in all instance of 2013 over your code

```
if ( ! write_file('C:\wamp\www\changeLog\changeLog' . date('Y') . '.txt', $message, 'r+'))
```

Codeigniter will create the file if it doesn't exists